# Displaying custom profile fields using Mingle Plugin

Tags: plugins, users, profiles

I am using the Mingle plugin to add some networking functionality for a website I am creating for a client. I am having Mingle handle displaying user profiles and friends, but WordPress to actually register users and put in fields.

Mingle has the ability to add custom fields (ex: Twitter, Facebook, etc). However, there is no way to display these custom fields individually. So, I have added my own custom fields to WordPress using the `functions.php` file:

```
function add_new_contactmethods( $methods ) {
    $methods['twitter'] = 'Twitter';
    return $methods;
}
add_filter( 'user_contactmethods','add_new_contactmethods' );
```

I am displaying them **within one of the Mingle templates** (`mingle/classes/views/mngl-profiles/profile.php`):

```
<?php if ( get_the_author_meta( 'twitter' ) ) { ?>
    <a href="http://twitter.com/<?php the_author_meta( 'twitter' ); ?>" title="Follow @<?php the_author_meta( 'twitter' ); ?> on Twitter">
        <div class="tile bg-color-twitter icon">
            <div class="tile-content">
                <img src="<?php echo THEME_DIR; ?>/images/icons/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" class="socialIcon" />
            </div>
            <div class="brand">
                <span class="name">@<?php the_author_meta( 'twitter' ); ?></span>
            </div>
        </div><!-- .tile -->
    </a>
<?php } ?>
```

Now whenever I go to a profile page that is generated by *Mingle*, (`http://example.com/admin` or `http://example.com/dylan`), whoever is currently logged in at the moment will have *their* custom fields shown, not to the user whose profile is being shown.

Does that make sense? I can provide more code or elaborate if need be. I would really, really appreciate any and all help I can receive on this, the project is really time-sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're outside the loop, so you should supply a user ID:

`get_the_author_meta( 'twitter', $user->id )`

Comment: Thank you for your help! What value should the variable `$user` hold?

Comment: I think it's available on the page, give it a try!

Comment: Right now when I use `get_the_author_meta( 'twitter', 1 )` it knows to display the custom field or not, and it retrieves the correct information. However, when I use `$user->id` it does not work, as if it is not retrieving the ID.

Comment: what about `$mngl_user->id`

Comment: That did not work. However, I was including this part of the code (because the client wants 15 social networking custom fields) so I included it in a file called <em>social-networks.php</em> then used `get_template_part('social', 'networks');` to include it in the Mingle template. Well, when I got rid of `get_template_part`, added `$user->id` and put all of the code just in the file, it worked. So `get_template_part` was the problem it seems. Thank you for your answer and help though, I got it figured out! :)